# How do I work with the geometry of Tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been having trouble wrapping my head around the geometry of Tkinter. I have a range of questions that I was hoping someone would be kind enough to clear up for me.

When making the rectangle in the below code I passed in 4 parameters. I'm aware that they're an x1, y1, x2, y2 parameter but how exactly does this work? I can't seem to create a rectangle of a specific size and place it exactly where I want. Also, what does the 20+20 thing mean in the 3rd and fourth parameter exactly?

How do I detect a specific coordinate? I would like to be able to detect the line on the screen and execute code based when the rectangle touches it but I'm clueless. I also can't position the line in the position I would want to either to emphasize how little I get Tkinter's geometry.

```
window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x200+450+300")

canvas1 = Canvas(window, width = 600, height = 300, bg='white')
canvas1.pack()
canvas1.create_line(25, 50, 50, 50)

robot = canvas1.create_rectangle(10, 10, 20+20, 20+20)

x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas1.coords(robot)

def right(event):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas1.coords(robot)
    canvas1.coords(robot, x1+10, y1, x2+10, y2)

def left(event):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas1.coords(robot)
    canvas1.coords(robot, x1-10, y1, x2-10, y2)

def up(event):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas1.coords(robot)
    canvas1.coords(robot, x1, y1-10, x2, y2-10)


def down(event):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas1.coords(robot)
    canvas1.coords(robot, x1, y1+10, x2, y2+10)



canvas1.focus_set()
canvas1.bind("<Right>", right)
canvas1.bind("<Left>", left)
canvas1.bind("<Up>", up)
canvas1.bind("<Down>", down)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you read up on [coordinates](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/coordinates.html) and the various [`create_x` methods](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_rectangle.html) and their parameters? About how to get stuff by coordinates and overlapping stuff, have a look at the various [`Canvas` methods](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html).

Comment: @tobias_k I have. I get the jist of x1 and y1 being point 1 and x2 and y2 being point 2 but it still confuses me. I can't get my head around it.

Comment: Can you get your head around _what_ confuses you, exactly, and tell us? Otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @tobias_k I try to execute code based on where the movable rectangle is but I never get the coordinates right. for example: `if x1 > 25 and x1 < 50:
        canvas1.pack_forget()` I put this in each keyboard event to try and get it to pack_forget if it went anywhere along the line on it's x-axis but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter canvas coordinates start with 0,0 at the upper left corner of the canvas. As X gets bigger the point moves to the *right*. As Y gets bigger the point moves *down*.

Consider this line of code:

```
robot = canvas1.create_rectangle(10, 10, 20+20, 20+20)
```

This creates a rectangle formed by the coordinates (10,10) and (40,40). Starting from the upper left corner, tkinter will count ten pixels over and ten pixels down to draw the first corner of the rectangle. The opposite corner of the rectangle is (40,22). It will look like this (not to scale):

```
  point 1 (10,10)
    +


                   +
                 point 2 (40, 40)
```

Tkinter will then create a rectangle by computing the missing corners wich are at (40,10) and (10,22)

```
  point 1 (10,10)
    +--------------+
    |              |
    |              |
    +--------------+
                 point 2 (40,40)
```

As for the second question (which really should be a separate question), you can determine if one object overlaps another with the canvas [find_overlapping](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method) method.

Comment: Thanks. That's cleared up rectangles. How exactly would I go about coordinate detection though?

Comment: @WewLad: use the [find_overlapping](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method) function to determine if two objects overlap

Comment: How exactly do I work with that function? I've googled some examples. It just seems to return a tuple. I'd like to fire code when it overlaps if possible.

Comment: For example is there a way I can return True from that for example?